# How to troubleshoot a virtual interface which is currently down?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

One of the virtual interfaces on my linux instances is showing `linkdown` when I run the command:

```
shell> ip route show
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-960qm6tr45nb  proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown
```

For now, I set `ignore_routes_with_linkdown=1` and the routing works fine. But I am not sure if this is the right practice.

Also, how to see what the actual root cause of the linkdown for that interface is? Rebooting did not help for this case and I could not find some other relevant logs.